# How to do a DELETE/UPDATE at the same time? Django rest ramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm new with django rest framework and I have **4 fields** in my database table (**id, chip, creation date, deletion date**), on the front-end there is a button to delete the chip, so far so good, but on the page I have, in addition to the abject (chip) to be deleted, it has 2 more fields (creation date and **deletion date**) when deleting the object, the deletion date field must have the time of deletion and not simply be empty. How to make this change when doing the deletion?`

at the moment I just created the model and migrated it to the database.

I haven't started yet, I just created a route to list (GET) all the data in the table.

I ask for help to do the Delete/Update or whatever it may be.

---

my model

```
class Gateway(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True)
    gateway_chip = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    deletion_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'GATEWAY'
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use both `PUT` and `DELETE` together, you can only specify one as the HTTP method. If you have a `deletion_date` field then presumably you don't want to actually delete the model object, otherwise why record the date? In that case, you can 'soft delete' the object - it still exists but you can filter it away so that users see it as having been deleted but system administrators can still access it.

You can still use the `DELETE` method despite this essentially just being an update as the process is still essentially a deletion. There is also no strict requirement that the `DELETE` protocol actually deletes anything.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the date of deletion field, it would be the user to know on the front-end that that chip is no longer in use. (inactive). Would this be a partial Update? Do you have an example of something similar?

Comment: It doesn't matter too much what the HTTP method is - if you are telling the user to delete something (even if you only soft delete it) then DELETE is fine, so it PUT